# How can the effects of a language be linguistically locked?

Tags: language, corporations

The ancient Sumerians were the first great empire on earth, worshipping a great elder god called "Mickey". After the empire fell, worshippers of the god went underground and continued to thrive. In the 20th century, these remnants established a global corporation called Disney, spreading worship of the god across the world through theme parks, movies, etc. This feeds the entity's power and allows it's influence to grow.

The Sumerians continue to use their ancient language for spells given to them through Mickey's power. The language's lexicon has been fully discovered and translated. However, when Sumerian is translated into other languages, such as English or Spanish, the spells simply don't work. For whatever reason, a spell must be conducted in its original language in order to be successful.

How can this be the case?

Comment: Sacred language is sacred. Spells must be spoken in the original Sumerian because spells must be spoken in the original Sumerian. There are multiple examples of this phenomenon. Judaic religious ceremonies must be conducted in Hebrew. Catholic exorcisms must be conducted in Latin. The Greek Orthodox Church conducts its ceremonies in Koine (= Common) Greek, the language of the New Testament. The Russian Orthodox Church conducts its ceremonies in Church Slavonic, the language of the Saints Cyril and Methodius. Look up [liturgical language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_language).

Comment: And of course the canonical example is the Holy [Quran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quran), which exists only in Arabic. There can be, by definition, no such thing as a translation of the Quran. All you can have is a translation of the *meaning* of the Holy Quran, which, unlike the Quran, is not the perfect and unchangeable word of God, but just an imperfect and mutable rendition of the meaning of the word of God in some human language, as far as the mortal translator was able to understand.

Comment: @Incognito  The first great empire on Earth was the Persian Empire during the Achaemenid dynasty.  The Sumerian "Empire", like the Babylonian "Empire", the Assyrian "Empire", the Egyptian "Empire", etc. was peanuts compared to the Persian Empire or the Roman Empire.

Comment: @M.A.Golding that is exactly what the entity wants you to think. Its powers are so vast as to cause mass delusion among historians, hiding its true history and motivations.

Answer (score 5):

**That's how the Magic of Diznee works!**

If the enchantment of access or the spell of activation is not done properly, the thaumological Interface returns an error, and the magipraxator must enact the ensorcellment again:

[Access Not Recognised](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjSZXYyuJ7s)

Some folk might say that it's just a computer algorithm programmed to expect input within certain parameters, a "voice print" if you will. The reality is simply that magic operates by certain Laws, and the Laws must be obeyed else the magic just won't work.

In this case, it's obvious that one of the laws is that Sumerian itself is the vehicle through which the work of dwimmery gets done. Counterfeits are not to be accepted. The basic law here is *words have power*. In this case, it's just that Sumerian words also have **authority**.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of sounds is peculiar of the specific language. Translation might give the meaning, but hardly keeping the meaning and the specific sequence of sounds.

The above is more easily understandable if you look at rhymes

Take Alighieri's Divina Commedia incipit:

*Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra v**ita***

*mi ritrovai per una selva oscura*

*ché la diritta via era smarr**ita***

While a translation might keep the general meaning, it's much more difficult that it will keep the rhyme vita/smarrita.

A magic formula is way more complex than a rhyme, thus any misplaced sound will simply void it. Think of it like the call sound made by the modems in the early ages of internet.